# Can Delphi created Soap server app run on linux?

Tags: linux, web-services, delphi, soap

I have been toying around with creating soap servers in Delphi then running and interacting with them being hosted on my localmachine via IIS.

I have a godaddy account that is linux hosting and I am curious if I'll be able to use the Delphi created Soap Servers on this hosting?

Comment: Godaddy allows you to switch between Linux and Windows hosting. Not sure of their policy with regard to ISAPI dll's though. Haven't been able to find anything on their support pages about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have 3 options:

- Run it through Wine which is very capable nowadays.
- Build it with Kylix if you can get hold of a copy.
- Build it with FreePascal.

Comment: @yms which compiler do you have in mind? The mono options I'm familiar with all involve a port of some form or another.

Comment: I had in mind the original Delphi.net compiler (not Prism), but now that I think about it again the Borland VCL dependency might not work in Mono.

Comment: About Kylix, see http://crosskylix.untergrund.net to compile an Elf/Linux executable under Windows, from Delphi IDE. I compiled some server programs using this. But you need a Kylix copy - from a Delphi 7 box, e.g.

Answer (score 5):

Free Pascal will be a good alternative. We have deployed several (commercial) applications that use the wst toolkit in Free Pascal to build soap services that run both on windows and linux. Steep learning curve, but once you 'get it' it works very good.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no. Delphi itself is a Windows product and you would need to compile your code differently for it to run on Linux.

You may be able to do this with [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/), which is supposedly compatible with Delphi at some level, but no guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi produces Win32 executables. You won't be able to run them on linux. You could try to run them within an emulator such as [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Wine isn't going to be viable IMO.  Typically your SOAP service is going to be a command-line executable in the cgi-bin directory.  They typically have very short lifetimes (less than a second) so running natively is a big help here.
Unless the system is smart enough to know that your Win-32 app needs to run under Wine, and not have to incurr the overhead of spinning up a Wine session, it won't work.